# How do I add a condition on bootstrap form select?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

What I plan on doing is to create a scoring section for my student grading class where a certain subject must be first chosen before being able to choose the activity. In other words, each subject has its own activities that's why a subject must be selected first before being able to choose an activity from its subject.

What I did is to add a conditional statement where my query must select the activity where the course_id = $courseTitle. $courseTitle = $_POST['courseTitle'] btw.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-exp" class="control-label mb-1">Subject</label>
<?php 
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from tblcourse");                        
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count > 0){                       
echo ' <select required name="semesterId" class="custom-select form-control">';
echo'<option value="">--Select Subject--</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo'<option value="'.$row['Id'].'" >'.$row['courseTitle'].'</option>';
}
      echo '</select>';
}
?>                                                       
</div>

<div class="col-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="x_card_code" class="control-label mb-1">Activity</label>
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from assessment_list where class_id = $courseTitle"); 
$courseTitle = $_POST['courseTitle'];                       
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count > 0){                       
echo ' <select required name="levelId" class="custom-select form-control">';
echo'<option value="">--Select Activity--</option>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo'<option value="'.$row['Id'].'" >'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}
     echo '</select>';
}
</div>
</div>
```

This is my php code on the first line by the way if someone is wondering:

```
<?php

    include('../includes/dbconnection.php');
    include('../includes/session.php');
    error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $alertStyle ="";
      $statusMsg="";

    $courseTitle=$_POST['courseTitle'];
    $courseCode=$_POST['courseCode'];
    $levelId=$_POST['levelId'];
    $semesterId=$_POST['semesterId'];
    $dateAdded = date("Y-m-d");


    $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into tblcourse(courseTitle,courseCode,levelId,semesterId,dateAdded) value('$courseTitle','$courseCode','$levelId','$semesterId','$dateAdded')");

    if ($query) {
        
       $alertStyle ="alert alert-success";
       $statusMsg="Course Created and Assigned Successfully!";
    }
    else
    {
      $alertStyle ="alert alert-danger";
      $statusMsg="An error Occurred!";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is not pretty clear but from what I understand is that, you have system where a person needs to select a "subject" first in order to check it's  specific "activity".

In my opinion, rather than using PHP directly into the selection criteria, you can use basic JavaScript to achieve the same thing more efficiently.

Here is a sample of something which I recreated using your question/concept (I'm using Bootstrap v5.3.0):

[image: GIF_description]

## HTML Code

(The activity select field is initially disabled and becomes enabled when a subject is selected)

```
    <form>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
            <select id="subject" class="form-select">
                <option selected disabled>-- Select Subject --</option>
                <option value="subject1">Subject 1</option>
                <option value="subject2">Subject 2</option>
                <option value="subject3">Subject 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="activity" class="form-label">Activity</label>
            <select id="activity" class="form-select" disabled>
                <option selected disabled>-- Select Activity --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

## JavaScript Code

(You can customize the subject and activity options by modifying the values and text in the JavaScript section. ***You can use your new PHP Code to fetch these details from your Database.*** When the form is submitted, you can retrieve the selected subject and activity values in your server-side code for further processing or grading.)

```
<script>
    const subjectSelect = document.getElementById('subject');
    const activitySelect = document.getElementById('activity');

    subjectSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const selectedSubject = this.value;
        if (selectedSubject) {
            activitySelect.disabled = false;
            // Remove existing options
            while (activitySelect.firstChild) {
                activitySelect.firstChild.remove();
            }
            // Create new options based on the selected subject
            if (selectedSubject === 'subject1') {
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity1', 'Activity 1');
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity2', 'Activity 2');
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity3', 'Activity 3');
            } else if (selectedSubject === 'subject2') {
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity4', 'Activity 4');
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity5', 'Activity 5');
            } else if (selectedSubject === 'subject3') {
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity6', 'Activity 6');
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity7', 'Activity 7');
                addOption(activitySelect, 'activity8', 'Activity 8');
            }
        } else {
            activitySelect.disabled = true;
            // Remove existing options
            while (activitySelect.firstChild) {
                activitySelect.firstChild.remove();
            }
            // Add default disabled option
            addOption(activitySelect, '', '-- Select Activity --', true);
        }
    });

    function addOption(select, value, text, disabled = false) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = value;
        option.text = text;
        option.disabled = disabled;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
</script>
```

## Suggestions

Lastly, just by looking at your code, I can tell that it's gonna cause lots of problems as you are not using **prepared statements or parameterized queries** to make your code more secure and immune to SQL injections.